# Por que a condição do while não é um loop infinito?

Tags: javascript, comparação, booleano

Por que a condição desse `while` não é um *loop* infinito?

```
function fibonacci(n) {


const fibSequence = [1];

let currentValue = 1;
let previousValue = 0;

if (n === 1) {
  return fibSequence;
}

let iterationsCounter = n - 1;

while (iterationsCounter) {
  currentValue += previousValue;
  previousValue = currentValue - previousValue;

  fibSequence.push(currentValue);

  iterationsCounter -= 1;
}

return fibSequence;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript é uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica e fraca. Isso significa que ela faz coerções de valores sempre que forem necessários para dar algum resultado válido.

Isso é o que dá má fama à linguagem, se não tivesse a tipagem fraca JS seria uma linguagem bem mais próximo de ser muito boa. Ela dá uma facilidade desnecessária para a pessoa aprender o básico e usar de um jeito aparentemente um pouco mais fácil, mas logo depois que você começa fazer coisas mais complexas ela se mostra um enorme problema, que vira piada em vários momentos entre desenvolvedores. Mas veja bem, isso não era para ser um problema, a linguagem foi criada para fazer algo muito simples e dar uma pequena animação ou fazer uma ação simples em uma página web muito simples. O problema foi que começaram fazer códigos complexos em uma página única que é uma verdadeira aplicação. A linguagem não é adequada para isso.

Então sempre que um local exija um valor booleano de falso ou verdadeiro, que é o caso de um `if` ou um `while`, o ideal é que seja gerado um valor booleano. Porém dentro da filosofia de JS de tipagem fraca, ela faz qualquer valor ser um booleano de alguma forma, ou seja, ela usa alguma regra própria para converter um outro valor, por exemplo um número, em um booleano. E tudo funciona.

Nesse caso há um valor em `iterationsCounter` que é considerado um valor [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), ou seja, é verdadeiro, porque bem poucos valores são considerados falsos. Quando essa variável atinge um valor [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) o `while` vira falso e termina.

Os valores falsos, conforme o *link* acima, são: `false`, `0`, `-0`, `0n`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`. Portanto quando a variável atinge o valor 0 a condição é falsa. seria o mesmo que dizer de forma mais explícita: `iterationsCounter != 0`.

O fato de escolhas ruins terem sido feitas ajudam dar alguns problemas, mas não nesse caso. Eu nem diria que essa forma é muito menos legível ou cause tanta confusão. Causa alguma.

Esse código tem pelo menos um *bug*. Se o valor for 0 ou negativo ele não funciona:

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
    const fibSequence = [1];
    let currentValue = 1;
    let previousValue = 0;
    if (n === 1) return fibSequence;
    let iterationsCounter = n - 1;
    while (iterationsCounter) {
      currentValue += previousValue;
      previousValue = currentValue - previousValue;
      fibSequence.push(currentValue);
      iterationsCounter -= 1;
    }
    return fibSequence;
}

fibonacci(0);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Fibonacci.js).

Seria bom testar isso antes de chegar no laço e decidir o que fazer, provavelmente nem retornando um resultado válido.